# How do I change values of list items inside another list?

Tags: python

I have a list **inside a list** containing 4 numbers, like this:

`[[1, 1000, 2000, 3000], [4, 3500, 2500, 5500]]`

The **second**, **third** and **forth** values of the inner list are measures in **milimeters**, that I must convert to both **centimeters** and **meters**. The first value must remain the same.

I'm not sure if my solution is working, but I'm pretty sure that there should be an easier way of doing it:

```
list = [[1, 1000, 2000, 3000], [4, 3500, 2500, 5500], [7, 1000, 200, 400]]
measures_in_cm = []
measures_in_meters = []

for i in list:
   i[1] = i[1] / 10
   i[2] = i[2] / 10
   i[3] = i[3] / 10
   measures_in_cm.append(i)

   i[1] = i[1] / 100
   i[2] = i[2] / 100
   i[3] = i[3] / 100
   measures_in_meters.append(i)
```

**OBS:** Pycharm highlights the `i[1]` and says "Unexpected type(s): (int, float)". Not exactly sure why

Comment: do not use `list` to name a variable because it is a built-in function in Python.

Comment: What does "OBS" mean?

Comment: Actually floating-point division is correct here and it is a false warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why Pycharm would complain, because your code runs just fine, mostly.

I say "mostly" because this does have one large problem.  Your list contains three lists.  First time through the loop, `i` refers to the first list.  You then divide by ten (still the same list), and append a reference to `measures_in_cm`.  You then divide that same list by 100 and append a reference to `measures_in_meters`.  However, `measures_in_cm` contains a reference to that same list, so its values will ALSO be divided by 100, AND the values in your original `list` will be divided by 1000.

Also note that it is unwise to name a variable `list`, because that hides the built-in `list` type.

```
for i in list:
    copy = [i[0], i[1]/10, i[2]/10, i[3]/10]
    measures_in_cm.append(copy)
    copy = [i[0], i[1]/1000, i[2]/1000, i[3]/1000]
    measures_in_meters.append(copy)
```

Now each list contains references to different lists.  If that seems a little "hardcoded", it's possible to do that with a list comprehension, kind of like:

```
    copy = [i[0]] + list(k/10 for k in i[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine and is quite readable. If you want to get fancier, you can mix all kinds of fun things together: list comprehension, functional programming, lambda functions, array slicing...

```
>>> measures_in_cm = [list(map(lambda x: x/10, x[1:])) for x in lst]
>>> measures_in_cm
[[100.0, 200.0, 300.0], [350.0, 250.0, 550.0], [100.0, 20.0, 40.0]]

>>> measures_in_m = [list(map(lambda x: x/1000, x[1:])) for x in lst]
>>> measures_in_m
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [3.5, 2.5, 5.5], [1.0, 0.2, 0.4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val_list = [[1, 1000, 2000, 3000], [4, 3500, 2500, 5500], [7, 1000, 200, 400]]

measures_in_cm = []
measures_in_meters = []

measures_in_cm = [[x if x == temp[0] else x/10. for x in temp] for temp in val_list]
measures_in_m = [[x if x == temp[0] else x/1000. for x in temp] for temp in val_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, another option could be the following:

```
list = [[1, 1000, 2000, 3000], [4, 3500, 2500, 5500], [7, 1000, 200, 400]]
measures_in_cm = [[i[0], i[1]/10, i[2]/10, i[3]/10] for i in list]
measures_in_meters = [[i[0], i[1]/100, i[2]/100, i[3]/100] for i in list]
```

Avoid using the name of the reserved word in your variables, like 'list'

Answer (score -1):

You can try `numpy` with list comprehension

```
lst = [[1, 1000, 2000, 3000], [4, 3500, 2500, 5500], [7, 1000, 200, 400]]
measures_in_cm = [[float(l[0])]+np.divide(l[1:], 10).tolist() for l in lst]

 [[1.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0],
 [4.0, 350.0, 250.0, 550.0],
 [7.0, 100.0, 20.0, 40.0]]
```